# Dominoes and Probability

Tags: probability

I started playing dominoes (7 bones, draw) a while ago and I was wondering does winning a match depend solely on luck or can understanding a bit of probability also work on ones favor? If so, what would be an example of applying probability to win?

Comment: I mean... theoretically there is an element of chance to the game in terms of in which order you draw the pieces and so there is a theoretical "best" way to play (*see [game theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) on wikipedia*).  As for how to capitalize on this, I have never given it any thought (*there are far more enjoyable games to play in my opinion*), ...

Comment: the answer to this question could be really complex, you are asking for some strategy to enhance the possibility of victory, but this depends on too many factors, not just probability

Comment: ...but consider an extreme situation where you are one turn from ending... having seen all pieces currently in play you can figure out what the final piece in the bag is and can use that knowledge to place the penultimate piece in a way to ensure the last piece can be played while avoiding a placement which would have left no legal placements for the final piece.

Comment: [This paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-07890-8_12) seems like it could be an interesting read related to your question.